# Add field metadata to django-rest-framework serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am writing an API using django-rest-framework that is used to display custom tables at the frontend.

I need to add metadata to the json returned by model serializer:

- provide custom display name for nearly all fields;
- mark some fields unsortable so that sorting controls are not displayed in the UI for corresponding columns;
- specify header rotation angle for narrow columns.

I tried googling this but all I find is how to add a custom non-model field to `ModelSerializer`.

Comment: I am trying to do this same thing.  If I figure it out, I'll let you know.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The display name can be modified by modifying the labels via `extra_kwargs` which provides arguments to the derived field instances. The other metadata is a bit more tricky. Therefore, we introduce an own dict `extra_meta` in the meta class. E.g.,

```py
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = sfmodels.Contact

        fields = [
            "first_name",
        ]        
        
        extra_kwargs = {
            "first_name": {
                "label": _("Your name"),
            }
        }
        
        extra_meta = {
            "first_name": {
                "sortable": False,
                "header_rotation_angle": 45,
            }
       }
```

Now, we extend the Metadata generator to use the extra data:

```py
from rest_framework.metadata import SimpleMetadata

class ExtraMetadata(SimpleMetadata):

    def get_serializer_info(self, serializer):
        """
        Given an instance of a serializer, return a dictionary of metadata
        about its fields.
        """
        # retrieve meta kwargs if provided
        extra_meta = copy.deepcopy(getattr(serializer.Meta, 'extra_meta', {}))

        # call the original implementation
        field_infos = super().get_serializer_info(serializer)

        # and add meta kwargs to the fields
        for field_name, field in field_infos.items():
            if field_name in extra_meta:
                for key, value in extra_meta[field_name].items():
                    field[key] = value
        return field_infos
```

Last, we tell the rest framework to [use our custom meta data generator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/#custom-metadata-classes):

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'myproject.serializers.ExtraMetadata'
}
```